# how to change user roles for users who doesn't have any. (about 8000 users)

Tags: user-roles

We have about 8000 users who doesn't have any roles. we need to change them to "contributor".
How can I change them to "contributor"?
Should I do on database? if so, which fields I need to update?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you don't set _any_ role for them? Please show us the entry from a user without any role and his usermeta value for `wp_capabilities`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by executing simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
   SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:11:"contributor";b:1;}' 
 WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
   AND meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'
```

This query will updated all subscribers to be contributors.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but some users don't have any roles. their's roles are "None". then how I need to update?

Comment: Find out what `wp_capabilities` meta contains for these users.

Comment: there is no wp_capbilities for some users. i can't find them on user-meta