# How can change 12000 user role into contributor by sql

Tags: user-roles

We have about 12000 users who doesn't have any roles. we need to change them to "contributor". How can I change them to "contributor"? Should I do on database? if so, which fields I need to update?

I try this code :-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO an_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT DISTINCT
u.ID, 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:11:"contributor";b:1;}'
FROM an_users u
```

But when go to `wp-admin` i don't see any user for contributor role
Thanks,

Comment: Do you already know how to add the user role of contributor to ***one*** user? You might to try that one first. Step by step.

Comment: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111642/how-to-change-user-roles-for-users-who-doesnt-have-any-about-8000-users?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Manually change 1 user to a contributor then view their wp_capabilities entry in wp_usermeta table.

Update the rest of the table to set wp_capabilities to this value for the 12,000 users.